# Sybase Advantage Database server and 64 bit VFP OLE providers

Tags: .net, sybase, 32bit-64bit, visual-foxpro, advantage-database-server

Does anyone know if the sybase ads vfp provider works in 64 bit?
Currently we have to build our .NET applications targeting x86 to be able to use the vfpoledb provider that only runs in 32 bit. Any solutions or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 64-bit version of the Advantage OLE DB Provider will be officially released in the v10 release coming up soon.  But I believe you can obtain a v9.1 beta version of the 64-bit provider if you contact them directly.